# Why is the startup.cs file not being used when I start my Azure Function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, .net-framework-version

I am trying to run an azure function app project locally.  I have breakpoints placed around my startup.cs file and I've noticed that they are never hit.  As a result, my dependency injection does not work.  I have been trying various combinations of nuget package versions, all to no avail.  Can anyone provide me with advice as to how I can get the startup.cs file to be used?

This is a Class Library project that targets **.Net Standard 2.0**

I'm using **Azure Functions Core Tools 3.0.2912** with Function Runtime version 3.0.14287

**Here is my solution explorer**

[image]

**Here is the start of my startup function**

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you sure that the breakpoints are set successfully?

Comment: @KarenMartikyan yes, the app builds successfully and the breakpoints remain a solid red circle.  I am also dealing with the error that says "function is in error: The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed." I am not sure if this is interfering with the startup process though

Answer (score 2):

There is an existing bug where the debugger attaches late, and early breakpoints, such as those in Startup.cs aren't able to be hit.
Have a look here
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/1971

To test if this is your situation, add a thread sleep of ten seconds into your startup.cs, then place a breakpoint after that.  Is it it?